# OpenCV blob detection: separate close blobs

Tags: c++, opencv, blob

I am using OpenCV + CvBlobs to detect items in an image. I sometimes get results like this:

[image]

How can I separate close blobs with low connectivity like the bottom left blob from the top right one ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can label it 4 neighbourhood algoritm or simply use morpohological opening filter.

Comment: I used an erode filter which accomplished what was required.