# How to separate two touching blobs?

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, scikit-image, canny-operator

I have written the following code in order to detect the blobs based on their `HSV` values, everything works fine, except that when the two blobs intersect(touch) the are detected as one instead of two. I have read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19916765/opencv-blob-detection-separate-close-blobs) that this can be solved, by using  `4-neighborhood` and [morphological filtering](https://scikit-image.org/docs/stable/auto_examples/applications/plot_morphology.html) operations, while I have not succeeded in implementing that in my code, I have tried `erode` operation, but that did not help because I had to combine it with `dilate`, and they are opposite operations no result was achieved, If I keep only `erode` all the blobs will be removed and the result will be a black image

This is the input image:
[image]

The ones on the left are combined as one blob, and I want to separate them, so that I have 7 blobs instead of 6.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

img = cv2.imread('./lemon.png')

hsv_img = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)

fruit_mask = cv2.inRange(hsv_img, *hsv_bounds[plant_name])
fruit_mask = cv2.cvtColor(fruit_mask, cv2.COLOR_GRAY2BGR)
result = cv2.bitwise_and(img, fruit_mask)

counter = {}
counter['lemon'] = 0

image_gray = cv2.cvtColor(result, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
image_gray = cv2.GaussianBlur(image_gray, (5, 5), 0)

image_edged = cv2.Canny(image_gray, 50, 100)
# kernel = np.ones((4, 4), np.uint8)

image_edged = cv2.dilate(image_edged, None, iterations=1)
# kernel = np.ones((4, 4), np.uint8)

image_edged = cv2.erode(image_edged, None, iterations=1)


cnts = cv2.findContours(
    image_edged.copy(), cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

cnts = cnts[0]

for c in cnts:

    if cv2.contourArea(c) < 200:
        continue

    hull = cv2.convexHull(c)
    img_mask = cv2.drawContours(result, [hull], 0, (0, 0, 255), 1)

    counter['lemon'] += 1

    print(counter)
    cv2.imwrite('./blob_testing/detected_55.png', img_mask)
```

Update:
Thanks to the comments, I understood my mistake, and I have added the `erode` to the drawn contours (not the canny edges), and that fixed the problem, and the result look like that:

[image]

I still need to draw the red contours around the blobs so that I can count them

Comment: show us how you tried to erode (code) and what happened (image). you also need to justify or remove everything else in that code. [mre]

Comment: I have just increased the number of iterations in my script, and tried to specify different kernel sizes, and I've mentioned in my question that when the kernel size for `dilate` is greater or equal to the kernel size specified for the `erode` the result is the image I  have shown, and when the kernel size for erode or the number of iterations is larger than the one for `dilate` I get blank image(black)

Comment: based on what I see, you'd just need one or two erosion iterations. then those blobs will be separated and you're done. -- an MRE also includes the source data because there's no way to run your code on data I have to imagine in my mind.

Comment: I have included the image, or in what format shall I upload it?

Comment: when I add one extra iteration of erode all the blobs disappear, and I end up with a blank image

Comment: I think what Chris means is you should run erosion on the drawn contours (not the canny edges). The canny edges are really thin so eroding there will remove most of them.

Comment: Thank you very much, now It is better, I have edited the question, may you please tell how can I add new drawn contours over the new result, so that I can count the blobs? I have tried to repeat the same line that I used to draw the contours initially but that did not help, Do I need to find the convex hulls again?

Comment: See watershed at https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/d3/db4/tutorial_py_watershed.html

Comment: Thank you, but should not it be simpler than that? I admit the link was helpful, but I really expected that it is a one liner operation to draw red contours around the blobs

Comment: what you claim to be the input image has convex hulls drawn on it.

Comment: @Josh,  No, unfortunately  it is not a one liner. You could try to apply morphology erode to a binary mask to separate them.

Comment: well, difficult to try your code without the original input images , but I am a novice probably should know better https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 1):

Why don't do your process on binary mask image?

Perhaps `fruit_mask = cv2.inRange(hsv_img, *hsv_bounds[plant_name])` is the mask.
If so, apply morophology(dilate, erode) to this mask to remove noise and separate blobs.
Then, `findContours` on the moropholygy result.

If the result is good(of course you can filter them further (e.g. based on area, shape, etc).), you can count contours, or draw contours on your input image if needed.